# How to calculate marginal effects with multinomial regression for survey data in R

Tags: r, survey, multinomial-logit, marginal-effect

I am trying to calculate average marginal effects for a multinomial logistic regression fitted using the `svrepmisc` package in R. The `margins()` function provides solution for binary logistic regression but it does not work for multinomial logistic regression. Is there a package to calculate marginal effects for survey multinomial regression in R? I have included an example illustrating what I have tried to do.

Using margins for `svyglm()` as follows,

```
# Binary logistic regression

data(api)
library(survey)
library(margins)

dclus1 <- svydesign(id = ~dnum, weights = ~pw,data = apiclus1, fpc = ~fpc) # survey design
model1 <- svyglm(api00 ~ api99 + sch.wide, design = dclus1) # fit model
margins(model1, design = dclus1) # margins
```

produces the following output:

```
Average marginal effects (survey-weighted)
svyglm(formula = api00 ~ api99 + sch.wide, design = dclus1)
api99 sch.wideYes
0.9071       47.48
```

I tried to use the `margins()` function for `svymultinom()` as follows:

```
# Multinomial logistic regression

library(svrepmisc)

rclus1 <- as.svrepdesign(dclus1) # survey design
model2 <- svymultinom(api00 ~ api99 + sch.wide, design = rclus1)
margins(model2, design = rclus1)
```

It produces the following error:

```
Error in model[["call"]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the author of the `svrepmisc` package that implements `svymultinom`. I admit that one of the main reasons this package is not on CRAN is that I never went to the trouble to make sure it integrated nicely with other packages like margins, and I also cannot 100% vouch for the accuracy of the variance estimators. Please use with caution.

Kind Regards,
Carl